# iphone UIview animation resize in like disappear in water and comes back floating

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, fadein, fadeout

I don't want to fade in and fade out like most common solution for the uiview animation. I would like to have the uiview resize to small until it disappear and comes back the same way. Another way to say it is having a camera pointing closely at the table with all the object in it (UIView) and camera backs up and the more it backs up the smaller the table gets. Which is why i titled which is mainly my app the whole uiview sinks into the water and floats back up. Hopefully i'll find a tutorial or someone's suggestion for the solution. everything resize/shrinks in the middle/center of the screen.

UPDATE***
i would like it to shrink in random position of the screen and appear from random position of the screen also.
Also my subview from other class is viewdidload in mainView 
(View = [[View alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 300, 300)];)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, where `view` is the view you are messing with:

```
CGRect originalFrame = view.frame;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    CGRect frame = view.frame;
    frame.origin = view.center;
    frame.size = CGSizeMake( 0, 0 );
    view.frame = frame;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // Do something with the view

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        view.frame = originalFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        return;
    }];

    return;
}];
```

Comment: thanks for your time. I have tried this and it moved the subview (View = [[View alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 300, 300)];) from other class to lower right and back to original frame. Its close but i would like it to shrink and come back after instead of moving it lower right and back. I also updated my post of the random position part.

Comment: Ok, try setting `clipsToBounds` on your view to `YES`, though that could cause a weird effect.  If it does, just let me know, I have another answer ready for you.

Comment: that works much better but it didn't shrink. it was going lower right disappearing in the box (bottom side and right side of the black park) you can see the sides as it disappear. also hoping to disappear in random position and appear random position =)

Comment: actually i got to see how it works since i made a color background and realized it shrinks the whole view. I decided to do the UIImageview of the similar way you mention. I also posted up that question hopefully you have answer for that too =)

Answer (score 0):

You can have that effect by shrinking the frame to size (0,0) over the center of some point on the screen

```
// assume float cx,cy are defined as center coordinates of your animation (ie where your image shrinks and grows from)
// assume CGRect animFrame is defined as the starting coordinates of your animationView
// assume you have outlet to animationView

// to shrink
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"WaterAnim" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.33];

        animationView.frame = CGRectMake(cx,cy, 0,0);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
// to grow
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"WaterAnim" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.33];
        animationView.frame = animationFrame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I've read from Apple documentation that the `beginAnimations:` `commitAnimations` method is no longer supported.  Methods like `[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]` are now encouraged.